# byte level difference between reading ASCII characters in objective c and c++

Tags: objective-c, ascii

i am facing a strange issue i have to encode/decode a network message in a QT and Objective C application, i have a magic key through which i encode the message data, the problem is that when i read the magic key file in c++ it gives the representation the same as the objective C shows, but on byte level there hexadecimal values are different, i tried it and read it in many ways in c++ but not working, how can i read it to get the exactly same hex values for both objective C and c++
(note: it does't give any problem on plain text and numbers, the problem is when i put some values in a text file which shows special characters)

Comment: "special characters" and ASCII rarely go together.  Other than C++'s lousy support for Unicode, why not use UTF8?

Comment: i was also thinking about utf8 but have't find any useful tip about reading a utf8 encoded file. i can't share my code coz its another pc with restrictions ....

Comment: @Noor - without the code or at least the pseudocode it's hard to tell what the problem is. Maybe if you give us some examples...

Comment: ok let me explain, i have a key file which i use in encoding/decoding of a message, if the key file contains some alphabets or numbers it works fine but when it comes to special characters inside the file the problem occurs, that is the characters which are in the file and the characters shown on C++ app console and the characters shown on Objective C console are all same but when i go to byte level representation of the files read values they are different from each other, i think the problem is utf-8 encoding of content because the Objective C is using UTF-8 when reading the file

Comment: since characters with an ASCII value of 127 or less are the same in UTF-8 it does not give any problem, but i have bigger values than 127